# Programatically check in C whether a NIC has link when it's DOWN in linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, ioctl

Is there a way to check if my NIC (which is DOWN) has a good link
to send/recv frames in C?

I tried checking the `IFF_RUNNING` and `ETHTOOL_GLINK` (respectively
via `SIOCGIFFLAGS` and `SIOCETHTOOL`) with ioctl but they only set this
information when the NIC is UP.

I also tried to directly check the `/sys/class/net/XXX/carrier` file but
I always get an **Invalid argument** when reading the file.

Does anyone know a way to get this information when the NIC is DOWN?

Comment: Perhaps thru some file inside `/proc/` ? Read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I didn't find anything so far. `/proc/net/dev` has some stats about the device but I didn't see anything that could be used to guess the link state. Any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can call out to `mii-tool` for this information, if available.  Some drivers will report the status when the interface is down, but many (most?) will not.

(It uses the `SIOCGMIIPHY` and `SIOCGMIIREG` ioctls).

Comment: It did work on my embedded linux but not in my Fedora 18 desktop (don't remember the NIC drivers). I'm not sure whether the latter result is valid because when I turned the NIC down the switch led also went down.. Maybe the NIC really lost the link in this case. In some other cases, the ioctl just returned `ENOTSUP` for non MII interfaces. I'll try a few more samples with these calls. thank you